# Prevent LyX from escaping math in color box title

Tags: lyx, tcolorbox

I'm trying to include some math in tcolorbox title, but LyX keeps escaping them. For example:

Color Box Options: `title={$\psi_{T}$}`

gives

`\begin{tcolorbox}[title={\$\psi\_{T}\$}]`

But I want

`\begin{tcolorbox}[title={$\psi_{T}$}]`

How to stop LyX from escaping `$` and `_`?

---

**Update:**

I am using LyX provided color box support. Here is the screenshot

[image: LyX colorbox screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this without going to TeX mode.
After digging into LyX source code, I found layout definition for Color_Box:

```
InsetLayout Flex:Color_Box
  LyXType               custom
  Decoration            classic
  LabelString           "Color Box"
  LatexType             environment
  LatexName             tcolorbox
  Requires              tcolorbox
  Argument 1
    LabelString         "Color Box Options"
    Tooltip             "Insert the color box options here (see tcolorbox manual)"
    PassThruChars       "\[]{}"
    DocBookTag          IGNORE
  EndArgument
  ResetsFont            true
  DocBookTag            phrase
  DocBookAttr           role='color-box'
End
```

`PassThruChars` means the white-listed chars. In this case I just need to add `$_` to it.

So I created a new layout and added these lines:

```
InsetLayout Flex:Color_Box_With_Math
  LyXType               custom
  Decoration            classic
  LabelString           "Color Box Math"
  LatexType             environment
  LatexName             tcolorbox
  Requires              tcolorbox
  Argument 1
    LabelString         "Color Box Options"
    Tooltip             "Insert the color box options here (see tcolorbox manual)"
    PassThruChars       "\[]{}$_"
    DocBookTag          IGNORE
  EndArgument
  ResetsFont            true
  DocBookTag            phrase
  DocBookAttr           role='color-box'
End
```

Now it's correct:

[image: correct result]

Comment: I didn't know LyX (I use it only to answer here) has support for `tcolorbox`, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Insert > TeX Code`?

Because I have your desired output if I put `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` in `Document > Setting > LaTeX preamble` and I wrote this

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={$\psi_{T}$}]
a box
\end{tcolorbox}
```

as LaTeX code (I have the Italian version of LyX, so the tabs are in Italian):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what I really want is doing this without going to TeX mode. I have figured it out, updated the question and posted my own answer.